# React hooks state : Undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

A novice at React over here, struggling with a basic useState hooks program. A simple functional component created named CounterHooks that aims at making a simple +-1 counter.

here is the  code :

The actual component is this.

`CounterHooks.js`

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react'
    export default function CounterHooks({initialCount})  {
      const [count , setCount ] = useState(initialCount) 
      return (
        <div>
                <button onClick = {() =>   setCount(  prevCount => prevCount -1 ) }>-</button>
                 {count}
                <button onClick = {  () => setCount(prevCount => prevCount +1 ) } >+</button>
        </div>
    
      )
    }
```

The component where it gets rendered.
`App.js`

```
    import React from 'react';
    
    
    import CounterHooks from './CounterHooks'
    function App() {
      
      console.log("Render App")
      
      return (
        <>
        CounterHooks
        <CounterHooks intialCount = {0} />
        </>
    
      ) 
    }

export default App;
```

[The output rendered is there in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzTrC.png)

and when i try to hit any of the buttons ,the output changes to NaN.

Please help me out , also let me know if  any other piece of necessary code is required for further clarification.

Much thanks.

Comment: Caused by typo, "intialCount" isn't the same as the destructured prop "initialCount". Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo at passing `initialCount` prop:

```
function App() {
  console.log("Render App");

  return (
    <>
      CounterHooks
      //            v not intialCount 
      <CounterHooks initialCount={0} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useState` only initialize once. When you pass down the `initialCount` prop down to `CounterHooks` component and use it directly for `useState` initial value, it won't update when the value `initialCount` updates to something that is not `undefined`. Hence state of `count` always remains `undefined`.

You would need to use `useEffect` here to keep the value of `count` in-sync whenever the value of prop `initialCount` updates.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
export default function CounterHooks({initialCount})  {
  const [count , setCount ] = useState(initialCount);

  useEffect(() => {
   setCount(initialCount) // update count after mount
  }, []);

  return (
      <div>
            <button onClick = {() =>   setCount(  prevCount => prevCount -1 ) 
        }>-</button>
             {count}
            <button onClick = {  () => setCount(prevCount => prevCount +1 ) } 
         >+</button>
    </div>

  )
}
```